# MongoDB aggregate framework very slow when have group

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I am trying to make an aggregate query with `"group"` to get the total of results.

The total of `"requested_items"` (my results) are +- 1.900.000.

If I execute with "group", the query is very slow (+- 300sec).

If I execute without "group", the query is very fast (+- 1sec).

What am I doing wrong?

The sample code is below.


**SLOW QUERY**

```
db.minute.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        $and: [
            { "status": "Homologado" },
            { "requested_items.status": /aceito/i },
        ]
    } },
    { $sort: {'_id': 1}},
    { $unwind: "$requested_items" },
    { $unwind: "$requested_items.winner" },
    { $match: {
        $and: [
            { "status": "Homologado" },
            { "requested_items.status": /aceito/i },
        ]
    } },
    { $project: {
        "_id": 1
    } },
    { $group: {
        "_id" : null,
        "total" : {$sum: 1},
    } },
], {allowDiskUse: true});
```

**FAST QUERY**

```
db.minute.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        $and: [
            { "status": "Homologado" },
            { "requested_items.status": /aceito/i },
        ]
    } },
    { $sort: {'_id': 1}},
    { $unwind: "$requested_items" },
    { $unwind: "$requested_items.winner" },
    { $match: {
        $and: [
            { "status": "Homologado" },
            { "requested_items.status": /aceito/i },
        ]
    } },
    { $project: {
        "_id": 1
    } },
], {allowDiskUse: true});
```

**DB STRUCTURE**

```
{
    "_id" : "12345678ABCD",
    "field_1" : [ 
        {
            "a" : null,
            "b" : "ABC"
        }, 
        {
            "code" : null,
            "b" : "ABCD"
        }
    ],
    "status" : "Homologado",
    "initial_date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T11:31:00.000Z"),
    "field_2" : [ 
        {
            "a" : "ABC",
            "b" : "ABCDE"
        }, 
        {
            "a" : "ABCF",
            "b" : "ABCDEF"
        }
    ],
    "field_3" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
    "field_4" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T13:54:48.000Z"),
            "a" : "Text",
            "b" : "More text..."
        }
    ],
    "field_4" : 12312321,
    "field_5" : ISODate("2016-05-24T13:55:00.000Z"),
    "field_6" : "ABCD",
    "requested_items" : [ 
        {
            "status" : " Aceito e Habilitado",
            "field_a" : "Text...",
            "winner" : [ 
                {
                    "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                    "b" : 130446,
                    "c" : 543223,
                    "d" : NumberLong(2),
                    "e" : "ABC 123 FULANO",
                    "f" : "text",
                    "g" : {
                        "description" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                    "b" : 130446,
                    "c" : 543223,
                    "d" : NumberLong(2),
                    "e" : "ABC 123 FULANO",
                    "f" : "text",
                    "g" : {
                        "description" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "field_c" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5744dd3271af88052f0cc343"),
                "a" : "TEXT",
                "b" : "TEXT"
            },
            "field_d" : NumberLong(2),
            "field_e" : 5223,
            "field_f" : "Não",
            "field_g" : "-",
            "field_h" : {
                "field_a1" : [ 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "field_a2" : [ 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "field_a3" : {},
                "field_a4" : [ 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T11:34:32.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:12:54.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:48:21.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:55:38.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:55:47.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T13:01:36.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T13:15:02.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "field_i" : "Não",
            "field_j" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "status" : " Aceito e Habilitado",
            "field_a" : "Text...",
            "winner" : [ 
                {
                    "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                    "b" : 130446,
                    "c" : 543223,
                    "d" : NumberLong(2),
                    "e" : "ABC 123 FULANO",
                    "f" : "text",
                    "g" : {
                        "description" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "field_c" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5744dd3271af88052f0cc343"),
                "a" : "TEXT",
                "b" : "TEXT"
            },
            "field_d" : NumberLong(2),
            "field_e" : 5223,
            "field_f" : "Não",
            "field_g" : "-",
            "field_h" : {
                "field_a1" : [ 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "field_a2" : [ 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "field_a3" : {},
                "field_a4" : [ 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T11:34:32.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:12:54.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:48:21.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:55:38.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:55:47.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T13:01:36.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T13:15:02.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "field_i" : "Não",
            "field_j" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "status" : " Aceito e Habilitado",
            "field_a" : "Text...",
            "winner" : [ 
                {
                    "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                    "b" : 130446,
                    "c" : 543223,
                    "d" : NumberLong(2),
                    "e" : "ABC 123 FULANO",
                    "f" : "text",
                    "g" : {
                        "description" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "field_c" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5744dd3271af88052f0cc343"),
                "a" : "TEXT",
                "b" : "TEXT"
            },
            "field_d" : NumberLong(2),
            "field_e" : 5223,
            "field_f" : "Não",
            "field_g" : "-",
            "field_h" : {
                "field_a1" : [ 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "field_a2" : [ 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "a" : "23213.213213.23/232-23",
                        "b" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:54:21.000Z"),
                        "c" : 103432446,
                        "d" : 522343,
                        "e" : "Sim",
                        "f" : NumberLong(2),
                        "g" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT",
                        "h" : "Sim",
                        "i" : {
                            "a" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "field_a3" : {},
                "field_a4" : [ 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T11:34:32.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:12:54.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:48:21.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:55:38.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T12:55:47.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T13:01:36.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-24T13:15:02.000Z"),
                        "A" : "TEXT",
                        "B" : "TEXT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "field_i" : "Não",
            "field_j" : 3
        }, 
    ],
    "field_7" : "TEXT",
    "field_8" : {
        "a" : "TEXT",
        "b" : "TEXT",
        "c" : "324234",
        "d" : "TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT"
    },
    "field_9" : 43234
}
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "status" : "Homologado"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "requested_items.status" : /aceito/i
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "module_database.minute",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [ 
                            {
                                "status" : {
                                    "$eq" : "Homologado"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "requested_items.status" : /aceito/i
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [ 
                                {
                                    "status" : {
                                        "$eq" : "Homologado"
                                    }
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "requested_items.status" : /aceito/i
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$requested_items"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$requested_items.winner"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$match" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "status" : "Homologado"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "requested_items.status" : /aceito/i
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "$const" : null
                },
                "numberOfdocs" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My server is:
OS: UBUNTU14/64
CPU: 6
RAM: 16 GB
Total Storage: 80 GB
Running just the tests of my question.

Comment: Bear in mind you have a lot of operations in your pipeline and the `$group` stage will group all the documents in the final pipeline. Again, you don't necessarily need the `$sort` pipeline if your group operation doesn't need any ordered documents getting in the pipeline, it's merely doing a count of all the incoming documents. Consider removing the `$sort` and the `$project` pipeline stages in your pipeline and see how that improves your performance.

Comment: What do you mean by `total of results` ? Can you show us your db structure?

Comment: @chridam, thanks for your answer. After removing the ``$sort`` and ``$project`` stages, the speed dropped to + - 250sec. Is still slow.

Comment: If the total count is all you are after then how about removing the `$group` operation altogether, replace it with the [**`$out`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) pipeline and output the results to another collection where you can use the [**`count()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) method on the output collection to get the total count?

Comment: @titi23, thank you for your edit and answer. I edited the question, now has the structure of my documents. ``total of results`` means the count of ``requested_items`` array. if my database only had the document that I put in the question, then the total would be 3.

Comment: @chridam, in this case, ``$out`` is very slow too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally solved the problem on my query with group.
It was an error of design patterns. Thinking in SQL world, I designed the collections before thinking about my app. As a result, slow queries.

To resolve it I had to redesign my collections and put the relevant data in first level of my docs.
In my searches, I found that on Aggregation, index needs to be in first stage of pipeline. If I use a field with index after the stage $unwind, it is not considered.

Besides that, I created an int hash for text fields using the package https://github.com/darkskyapp/string-hash. So, my text fields can be indexed.

So my queries changed from 300s to 5s.

Comment: Great! Could you pls provide the final data design and fast query so we can understand exactly what you did?

Comment: Grouping in aggregation uses indexes... if your grouping is slow, make sure that matching indexes exist.

Answer (score 2):

it is hard to determine speed as we don't have environment details.
What you could try to see how explain is predicting you query by adding:

```
{
   explain:true
}
```

to your aggregation query  `db.coll.aggregate([pipeline], {explain:true},{allowDiskUse: true})`. 
What also need to be considered that `$unwind` doubles amount of documents  to process.

As you re going to count amount of documents -> **it could be faster** just take [size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of an array (after first unwind) and sum it later

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $group: {
            _id: null,
            numberOfdocs: { $sum:{$size: "$requested_items.winner" }}
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

### EDIT

after playing with this query I was able to reduce it execution time circa 45%.
The main point is to skip second `$match` as this scans full result set , so last `$group`  contains all data and we can filter out what's needed at the end as this operation is done on a small result set.

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                "status" : "Homologado"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$requested_items"
        }, {
            $unwind : "$requested_items.winner"
        }, {
            $project : {
                x : "$requested_items.status",
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : "$x",
                numberOfdocs : {
                    $sum : 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                "_id" : /acesssito/i
            }
        }
    ], {
        allowDiskUse: true
});
```

Comment: I edited the question with result  of Explain and server info.
Size of array after first unwind don't worked.

Comment: @GabrielCunha could you tell me what is the name of field '"$requested_items.winner"' in showed document - i was trying to play with that, but as I'm unsure what I need to unwind in 2nd unwind...

Comment: question edited again. Now showing where is the ``winner`` field. I'm reading about integrate MongoDB with Redis for solution this performance problem. What do you think about?

Comment: @GabrielCunha please test my edit, and integration with redis is a nice solution, especially when this aggregation query will be hammering database